# Create and Update Records in Multiple Lists in SharePoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint 2013, i am designing relational lists which will be displayed in one single form. For example, I have 4 lists;

- List A
- List B
- List C
- List D

For every record that is created in List A, I would like to write about 20 records of related information in List B, List C and List D. What is the best way to perform **CRUD operations** in this case? Kindly suggest.

**Note:** I also have **lookup** information in other 4 lists which are just used for lookup and display.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I can use only JSOM and environment is Office 365

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an event reciever which handles ItemAdded event. Refer to this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx) on how to create one.

Evey time an item is added to list A, you will be able to programmatically add items to other lists and do other operations as well.

For an Office 365 solution check Remote Event Receivers [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can use only JSOM and environment is Office 365

Comment: Can you deploy a CSOM Remote Event Receiver? Updated my answer.

Comment: Nope, I can only use JSOM as of now

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this using "ItemAdded" event receiver.

**NOTE:**
If event receiver is scoped to "*Site*" then it will fired for all lists. So to run the event receiver on specific list only then, you must ensure that your event receiver scoped to "*Web*".

However we can also force Site Scoped event receiver to work for specific list by checking the List Name. Following code will help you.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            try
            {
                if (properties.ListTitle.Equals("List-A"))
                {
                 //Get current item values as below.
                 string name=properties.ListItem["Name"].ToString();
                 //Get your lists (List-B,C..) here and update the field you want.
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }

        }
```